# AWS S3 404 errors slowing down performance significantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm uploading images from my Rails app directly to S3. When I load up an index page that shows the images, its retrieving the image url directly from S3.

What I'm trying to do is to check if the S3 image exists using their 'exists?' method in the API documentation, and if the image exists, show that image, and if it doesn't exist, show a default image that's stored in my asset pipeline.

I'm able to do this, however the performance becomes really slow (10 sec load time!) and from my logs, its due to all the 404 KeyNotFound errors that returns for images that don't exist. When I retrieve all the images without doing this exists? check, the page loads significantly faster (less than 1 sec - the images that aren't there are just blanks on my web page).

How can I get around this? I would like to show a default image in the case of a missing image.

Answer (score 0):

Store the images on S3, but keep view fragment caches containing the images on your server.

The first page access that tries to show the image will incur the cost, but thereafter, cache hits will mitigate the response time for other attempts to show that image.

With some relatively simple fragment cache management logic, this can work out quite well for caching pieces of views that take "too much time" to assemble.

The models whose views are being cached are responsible for expiring caches containing their data - when a model instance's cached data is changed, it blows away just its cached data fragments that show that piece of data -- not necessarily all cached views showing its data, just those affected.

I've used different fragment caches for index views, show views, and when an model's data appears in the "related items view" of a different model.